# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de datatable en variables diferentes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Pues tengo un metodo que crea la consulta a la base de datos y me devuelve el valor de la consulta en la fila 0, 1, 2 etc... hasta ahí todo bien, pero si la consulta devuelve solo 1 registro pues me da error de (

> No hay ninguna fila en la posición 1.

Claro comprendo y es logico cual es el error, pues no hay sino 1 registro y yo estoy llamando la fila1, 2, 3 ,4 etc, cómo soluciono este error si cada valor de cada fila lo necesito como una variable diferente? probe con

> if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)  if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)  if (dt.Rows.Count > 2)

pero eso es poco practico si tengo que crearlo por 100 registros o mas,aunque hasta el momento el mas alto es de 69 registros.

```
public string ChartDataIndividualTitleRow1 = null;
public string ChartDataIndividualTitleRow2 = null;

 protected void fillDataCharIndividual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string (...)
        {
            con.Open();
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FUNCIONARIO FROM TABLA WHERE MES = @MES", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MES", ddlMes.SelectedValue);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                    ChartDataIndividualTitleRow1 = "'" + Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["FUNCIONARIO"]) + "'";
                    ChartDataIndividualStringRow1 = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["STRING"]);
                    ChartDataIndividualTitleRow2 = "'" + Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[1]["FUNCIONARIO"]) + "'";
                    ChartDataIndividualStringRow2 = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[1]["STRING"]);                

                    con.Close();

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza un [bucle for](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) que itere desde la primera fila a la última:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < dt.Rows.Count ; i++){

    ChartDataIndividualTitleRow = "'" + Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["FUNCIONARIO"]) + "'";
    ChartDataIndividualStringRow = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["STRING"]);

    //Tratamiento de esos datos...
}

con.Close();
```

No es necesario utilizar sentencia `if/else` puesto que si `dt.Rows.Count` es 0 no entra en el bucle.

Comment: Gracias por su comentario compa, estuve leyendo el enlace y creo comprender lo que hace el bucle, supongo está sería una parte de la solución, sólo me faltaría obtener o crea una variable para cada registro que recupera el bucle. (muy buena la aclaración de no necesitar el `if/else`)